# jQuery not posting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im having trouble trying to post data correctly using jQuery/AJAX

I have the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notifyPPAComplete() {
        $.ajax(
        {
        type: "POST",
        url: "PsychometricTest.aspx/UpdateDB",
        data: {'3'},
        dataType: json,
        success: success,
        contentType: application/json
        });
    }          
    $.post('PsychometricTest.aspx/UpdateDB', function(data) {
        alert ('success');
    });
</script>
```

I dont seem to receive my alert after the post neither, can anybody see an obvious problem?

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error in line 6, you are missing quotes

Comment: Yeah the function is being called as if i add an alert before $.ajax that works, ahh sorry I'll add them now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data: {'3'}
```

That's an invalid javascript literal. You may try like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ model: { foo: '3' } })
```

Notice the usage of the `JSON.stringify` method which serializes a javascript literal into a JSON string. It's natively built into modern browsers. And if you need to support legacy browsers you vould include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script.

Also `contentType: application/json` is pretty invalid javascript. Should be:

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

Also: `dataType: json` is invalid. Should be `dataType: 'json'`.

So at the end of the day:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notifyPPAComplete() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PsychometricTest.aspx/UpdateDB",
            data: JSON.stringify({ model: { foo: '3' } }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {

            },
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
    }          
</script>
```

would successfully post to:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateDB(MyModel model)
{
    ...    
}
```

where MyModel:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are right that the OP's data param is malformed, but you do not need to stringify the data param. You can pass a string or an object as data and jQuery will do what's right.

Comment: @JAAulde, in fact you need to stringify. That's how ASP.NET [PageMethods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) work. They expect a JSON request. Of course the OP should have probably explained in his question that he is using ASP.NET and he is trying to invoke a PageMethod as this fact might not be obvious to people not using ASP.NET. The OP should have used proper tags in his question to clearly state his scenario. Failing to do so made his question completely meaningless to people not familiar with ASP.NET.

Comment: My console throws up the error, "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'model'."

Comment: @Liam, I have updated my answer. Try using `data: JSON.stringify({ model: { foo: '3' } })`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Hmmm, I didn't see any mention of ASP in the OP, but I do see it in his URLs now that you mention it. I don't know anything about ASP, but yeah if some server code expects a JSON serialized set of input, then you'd have to stringify. I simply meant that it isn't a requirement for jQuery itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function notifyPPAComplete() {
            $.ajax(
            {
            type: "POST",
            url: PsychometricTest.aspx/UpdateDB,
            data: {'3'},
            dataType: json,
            success: function(success){a = success},<-- here use the function() 
            contentType: application/json
            });
        }          
        $.post('PsychometricTest.aspx/UpdateDB', function(data) {
            alert (data); <-- here use the variable not the literal string
        });
    </script>
```

and by the way you have $.post and $.ajax ??? is this a homework ?

Comment: then accept this question or tell me what do you need exactly

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet `notifyPPAComplete()` never gets called and `$.post('PsychometricTest.aspx/UpdateDB` doesn't post any data.

Also try using [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) in Firefox for better AJAX debugging.

It should be:

```
$.post('PsychometricTest.aspx/UpdateDB', { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
        alert ('success');
    });
```

where `{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }` is the data you want to post.